# Spirit realm explanation from Kung Fu Panda 3

Tags: plot-explanation, kung-fu-panda-3

Early in the movie Kai collects enough chi to leave the spirit realm.

So why is it that later when Po brings them both to the spirit realm Kai doesn't simply return to the mortal realm? He had more chi than before. Was it insufficient?

Is it that the chi he got was good enough for only a one trip and can't be reused, and the total chi he got thereafter was insufficient?

Or something like that?

Comment: He simply didn't care much where he'll fight Po. If he won he'd get back.

Comment: @Mithoron but why would he need to fight Po?

Comment: Geez, to get he's chi... He went all the way to this village to do this.

Comment: @Mithoron that was assuming Po was in the mortal realm. Now that Po was in the spirit realm why doesnt Kai just go back to the mortal realm and accomplish all his other objectives?

Comment: It would be out of character for him.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40732/discussion-between-mithoron-and-bclc).